# Is this Java Compiler error message incorrect? (byte loss of precision)

Tags: java, bug, oracle

The following IMHO valid java program doesn't compile because the Oracle 1.7 javac compiler thinks there's a possible loss of precision in lines 5 and 6. If you uncomment line 3 and comment out line 4, it compiles fine.

Would someone explain why the compiler believes there is a loss of precision on the assignment to either byte `b2` or `b3`?

```
public class BUG {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        //final byte b1 = 9;
        byte b1 = 9;
        final byte b2 = -b1;    // fine if line 3 is uncommented and line 4 is commented
        final byte b3 = 0 - b1; // fine if line 3 is uncommented and line 4 is commented
    }
}
```

If my sample code is correct, then I'd like to report this as a bug but I can't find out where. Would someone explain what the compiler error message is saying in this case and why it's correct?

Comment: If you think you've found a bug in a compiler or other basic tool used by thousands of people, you're *usually* wrong (not always, but you are in this case).

Comment: BUt *if* it were a bug, you could report it here: http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. I was thinking of doing this myself but I wasn't sure if this was considered done in this forum.

Comment: As long as you don't fundamentally change what you asked, you (and anyone else, for that matter) are free to edit your question to make it easier to grasp.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's acting exactly as specified.

With the `final byte b1` the compiler is sure that `b1` will have the value `9` and `-b1` becomes a [*compile time constant expression*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). The compiler can then check that the value is still acceptable for a `byte` and let's you do it.

When `b1` is **not** `final` then `-b1` is an expression like any other and as such `b1` will be promoted to `int` (see [JLS §5.6.1. Unary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1)). And since the conversion from `int` back to `byte` *can* result in loss of precision, the compiler doesn't allow it (without an explicit cast).

Comment: Thanks Joachim. Are you saying that '-b1' in the context of `byte b1` results in an `int`? I'd have to read up the language spec if that's true...

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: exactly. I've edited my answer to link to the relevant part of the JLS.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if I like this idea of promoting `byte` expressions to `int`s. I wanted to write some document some code using `byte`s to indicate the range of the expressions was in the `byte` realm. If I have to cast the results of promoted values back to `byte`, this completely defeats the purpose of the exercise. Anyway, I'll study the section in the JLS.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: `byte` is a definite second-class citizen in the Java world, and only existed because they really couldn't do without it. For any kind of calculation `int` and `long` behave much more natural.

Comment: It's also how C does it, which in turn reflects how CPU's typically work.

Comment: @MSalters: as far as I remember (and my C is very rust), C is more lenient with automatic conversion, so I don't think you need an explicit cast for `char x = -someInt;`, do you?

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Indeed not. The type system rules to deduce the expression type may be identical here, the consequences of the resulting type mismatch are not.